# Column type changes to "unknown" when its values are all the same

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, knitr, column-types

When I create a dataframe, columns with the same values in every row automatically set to type "unknown" and it is not possible to change it.

Here is an example for your better understanding:

```
data <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1), c(1:4), c(4:1))
colnames(data) <- c("Not Working", "Ok", "Ok")
```

The first column of such data frame ("Not Working") is filled with the same values (all 1).
As you run the code, you'll notice that its type is "unknown", while "numeric" is automatically set for the others.

If you try to change it though, nothing works. For example:

```
data$`Not Working` <- as.numeric(data$`Not Working`)
data$`Not Working` <- as.numeric(as.character(data$`Not Working`))
```

You'll see that the column type is still the same using both string of code. Neither change anything using brackets instead of the dollar sign.
This happens every time a column gets all its values equal. I also tried to turn the data frame into a matrix first and then into a data frame again, or to change columns into factors first (even if is meaningless for my specific kind of data) and then into numeric, but nothing works.

And although this is not a problem for a classic R script, it turns to be crucial when I try to knit the file, returning the following error:

```
"Error [...]: replacement has length zero"
```

After several test, I found out that the error is specific for the column type that should be numeric. I have R markdown and Latex properly installed, so it should be nothing about that.

Does anyone know why this happens and if there is a way to fix it? It looks like a bug or something, but I've already tried to update the program at the latest version but nothing changes.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error from your example. The code looks fine. I would suggest that you run `sessionInfo()` and paste the result, run `str(data)` and show us the result and also exactly reproduce your code that is producing the error.

Comment: How would you ever expect a dataframe with duplicate column names to possibly work? Accesses like `data$Ok` would be ambiguous (apparently the first match is used; but they might break in dplyr or other libraries). Also, to avoid grief best to mangle spaces in column names to underscores, and uniquify names e.g. `Ok.1, Ok.2`, see [`make.names()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html)

Comment: I can't reproduce this either, `str(data)` confirms the first column of your dataframe is numeric. Be aware that naming your dataframe `data` shadows the builtin `utils::data`.

Comment: Do you actually have any legitimate reason for wanting to give both columns 2 and 3 the duplicate name 'Ok'? The colnames of a dataframe are not really a "zero'th row" where you can store whatever you want without consequence. Unless you have a compelling reason for needing to do this, don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should not have two columns with the same name. I would recommend you use `tibble` to create data frames.

```
library(tibble)
data <- tibble("Not Working" = c(1,1,1,1), "Ok" = c(1:4), "Oki" = c(4:1))

sapply(data, class) #check the data types
```

If you want to change a data type of a column to something specific you can easily specify that.

```
data <- tibble("Not Working" = as.character(c(1,1,1,1)), "Ok" = c(1:4), "Oki" = c(4:1))
```

Comment: Could you add why you would recommend tibble?

Comment: It is essentially just a more modern take on a data frame that is very easy to use with some of the ineffective parts removed and new additional features added. It doesn't change variable names or types, and doesn't do partial matching but it does complain more (e.g. when a variable does not exist) and forces you to confront problems early on. Tibbles also have an enhanced print() method which makes them easier to use with large datasets containing complex objects.

Comment: Sorry, maybe wasn't clear, how recommending tibble solves the OP's problem (plus the problem still seems to be unclear to be answerable)?

Comment: Well in this case when I ran it with `tibble` the "Not Working" column type was automatically set as numeric and not as unknown.

Comment: `all(
  tibble::tibble("Not Working" = c(1,1,1,1), "Ok" = c(1:4), "Oki" = c(4:1)) ==
    data.frame("Not Working" = c(1,1,1,1), "Ok" = c(1:4), "Oki" = c(4:1), check.names = FALSE)
)` will give us `TRUE`. In this case tibble is not doing anything new what base data.frame could do.

Comment: In that case the problem is not reproducible, however I still think `tibble` makes it easier to manage data types.

Comment: I am not saying tibble is not a good package. I am saying it is not relevant to OP's problem (which is not reproducible, and not clear).